# Ubuntu HUD in Mac OS

Tags: macos, unix

Is there and app or something that gives Yosemite the functionality that [Ubuntu HUD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_WW-DHqR3c) has - search menu for items?

I am switching to Mac from Ubuntu. Even thou I was on Ubuntu Linux for only a few weeks and originally came from a Windows background, I got super used to the HUD  functionality. I would like to take that with me if possible.

Comment: Nothing quite like that. I use Keyboard Maestro to program my function keys to invoke apps and perform repetitive tasks.   In macOS, you can use the same function key to open and app and switch to an app, very handy. It has a bunch of built in functions you can chain together to do what you want.  You can invoke a scripting language to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Spotlight** on OS X is the closest built-in feature, [Use Spotlight in OS X Mavericks to find files and more](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht2531).

There are third party alternatives that have additional functionality. Well known examples include:

- [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com)
- [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/)
- [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com)

Comment: Thanks for answering. They all seem to be searching the wider scope than the current programs menu. I think the spotlight will suffice for my needs for that.
But i need something also for the smaller scope :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to search the menu of the active program, the Help menu generally includes a search feature that does exactly this.

If you wish to bind it to a key for quick access, that can be done in the Keyboard preference pane, under the Shortcuts tab. Select "App Shortcuts" from the box on the left, and create a shortcut for "Show Help menu".

Comment: The standard shortcut for the help menu is `Cmd + Shift + /` (`7` on an German keyboard)
@MihkelL. As an asker, you can [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Even with no reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Sorry, It seems I just remapped the default <kbd>Cmd+Shit+/</kbd>. Thank Mihkel L. for pointing to me this.

It's a builtin feature in macOS now. (At lease 10.12)

[image: Show Help menu in All Applications]

In the screenshot above, I use `F1` to trigger the help menu search.

Comment: you just remapped `Cmd + Shift + /` shortcut. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember I changed it once.